# i am trying to create a simple api to recieve any format of json data but getting 400 bad request.. please have a look to my code and correct

Tags: json, rest, api, flask, flask-restful

```
    from flask import Flask, abort, request
    import json
    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
    def data():
        if not request.json:
            abort(400)
        print(request.json)
        return json.dumps(request.json)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True)
```

i want to send all my post request to another endpoint at localhost:8000.. please suggest the corrections`enter code here`

Comment: What have you tried so far? What other resources have you consulted prior asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried run your code, it works fine, here is my exmaple:

Server same as yours. One suggestion about your code: `.json` attribute has been deprecated, you should use the `request.get_json()` method.

```
   from flask import Flask, abort, request
    import json
    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
    def data():
        if not request.json:
            abort(400)
        print(request.json)
        return json.dumps(request.json)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True)
```

client:

```
import requests
res = requests.post('http://localhost:5001/data', json={"mytext":"test"})
if res.ok:
    print(res.json())
```

I guessed you don't fire the right HTTP request. for exmaple, do you add attribute `Content-Type: application/json` in your http header?

Comment: i did use postman to post the following json {"event": "$set", "entityType": "user", "entityId": "aditya", "properties": {"Designation": ["trainee"]}, "eventTime": "2015-10-05T21:02:49:228Z"}

Comment: Also i want to dump all the POST reuest to another endpoint like localhost:8000.. i am new to flask so don't really know where and how should i add the endpoint inside this code to dump my data.